Spring Boot audio endpoint: releasing JDBC resources much slower on VPS, fast on localhost
I have this code in a @RestController:
    @GetMapping("get_sound/{name}")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getSound(@PathVariable(name = "name") String name) throws IOException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("started getSound " + name);

        String fullPath = this.fileService.path() + "/" + name;

        File file = new File(fullPath);

        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        int numBytes = fileContent.length;

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("elapsed for getSound " + name + "= " + elapsed);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("audio/mpeg"))
            .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
            .body(Arrays.copyOfRange(fileContent, 0, numBytes));
    }

On a frontend I have
<audio src="http://localhost:8082/api/get_sound/sound.mpeg"></audio>

element. When I try to fast forward or backward to a specific time by clicking on the timeline, it works.
However while in localhost it takes usually less than 100ms, when deployed on VPS (both frontend and backend are deployed on the same VPS, on a machine with the same IP address), each request to get_sound endpoint takes around 10 seconds.
The elapsed time for getting the byte[] of the audio file, however, takes very little - 20ms on average for VPS and 10ms for localhost. While there is a difference between VPS and localhost here, it's very little in absolute terms and isn't what causes seconds worth of delay.
I noticed that after each time the get_sound endpoint is hit, the Spring console has output  like this
TRACE 370406 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources

While on localhost it appears almost immediately after the elapsed time is displayed, on VPS it's seconds until the Releasing JDBC resources is displayed, long after the elapsed time is displayed. I've been wondering if that's what causes worse performance on VPS.
However the get_sound endpoint doesn't access the SQL database, only the filesystem. And I'm not sure why it would take so much longer to release resources on VPS, compared to localhost.

It is due Open Session in View
So since you request is 10 seconds long db connection is being open at start of request and close only after request is completed
Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view

Spring opens a new Hibernate Session at the beginning of the request. These Sessions are not necessarily connected to the database.
Every time the application needs a Session, it will reuse the already existing one.
At the end of the request, the same interceptor closes that Session.

We had similar issue causing performance issues in production and disable it by using this
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
Also i have use https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody in past to know exactly what might be taking time . you can check which code or sql query if any is causing problem
Example:

Not sure but may be this can be useful to you as well
for image , audio or other file , i think you can use sometime like https://min.io/ instead of spring boot handle such request

Thank you for your answer. I turned off open session in few - both on localhost and on VPS, but unfortunatelly VPS response time is still the same, despite the resources released message appearing sooner. I even tried to use Insomnia to send requests to localhost/VPS directly, specifying the Range: bytes=8650752- header, and for the same request, asking for the same bytes, the localhost performs in 150ms, and the VPS in 7 seconds! The amount of data being sent from the backend is 10MB
